# sample size and multilevel modelling

Tags: r, mixed-model, experiment-design, multilevel-analysis, statistical-power

I have y=f(X) 
where :
y is user performance,
X has 16 predictors (X1, .....X16) divided into two sets: 
 X1 ... X10  are the user parameters , and
 X11... X16  are the task parameters.

I want to set up some different experiments (to get variation in the task parameters )  that will be done by the users in order to find the relationships between the variables above.

Saying we have N different tasks. There are two suggestions to distribute these tasks over the users (M):

1- Each user do all N tasks.
2- Dividing the users in groups, so each group(with Mi users) do some tasks (Ni) which are different from what they are done by other groups.

My question is how to do pre-power analysis to find the number of tasks and users in both cases above.(*i.e.* N (or Ni) and M (or Mi))

And which type of multilevel modeling for both cases?